# Как поставить редирект с site.ru// на site.ru/

Tags: modx, redirect

Как поставить редирект с `site.ru//` на `site.ru/`? Совсем не получается настроить.

```
# MODX supports Friendly URLs via this .htaccess file. 

php_flag display_errors on

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: web-сервер какой?

Comment: хостинг на masterhost в принципе можно ковырять .htaccess

Comment: @reddyk А зачем Вам это нужно? Стандартная ошибка 404 будет в самый раз. Либо укажите используете ли Вы модуль rewrite для Apache, если да, то какие правила там уже установлены. Требуется больше конкретики.

Comment: для поисковых систем

Answer (score 2):

Для Apache mod_rewrite:

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Для nginx:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

Подробнее:

- http://www.nginxtips.com/nginx-remove-trailing-slash/ (англ.)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642696/ (англ.)

Comment: поставил не работает

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется сама ситуация, в которой требуется перенаправление с site.ru// требует рассмотрения. Надо избавляться от причины, а не от следствия.

Comment: был бы рад избавиться от этой проблемы

Comment: Опишите ситуацию в которой идет обращение к site.ru//